# How to handle binary files with Google Cloud SQL and Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I'm new in Google Cloud and I wanted to know how I should handle the following situation:

I have a Cloud SQL instance with some tables that contains information about media files. Basically, the media table will have meta data about the files and a symbolic link to tell their file path in Google Cloud Storage.

Since Cloud SQL and Cloud Storage are fully managed, can the files get out of sync with the database due to maintenance work?

Comment: what do you mean by out of sync? do you mean when the media file in Cloud Storage being updated, or removed, you would also update or remove the meta record in Cloud SQL? if yes, you could use a Cloud Function, which is triggered by Cloud Storage event (create/overwrite/delete), to update the record in Cloud SQL. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage